# Extracting Json data for data within JSON arrray

Tags: c#, .net, json, extract

I have a JSON file as defined below

```
{
   "student":{
      "fullName":"Max",
      "id":40425,

   "content":[
      {
         "subject":{
            "language":"medium"
         }
      }
   ]
   }
}
```

I am trying to extract data from here , however I am unable to extract the data within the JSON array . For example I can obtain the student full name max by specifying as `student.fullName` whixh returns Max but when I try to extract the subject language as `student.content.subject.language` it returns null.

What am I doing wrong here , what way can I extract the subject language as english ?

Comment: use `content.subject.language` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
student.content[0].subject.language
```

would give you medium since content is array.

Answer (score 0):

in JSON `{ }` is used for Object and `[]` is used for Array. So in your JSON file, the **content** property is an array. To access **subject** from **content**, you would use `student.content[0].subject.language`